# Django time convert format

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to convert time into specific format using following code:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=14), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

I am getting error that the first parameter has to be string.

I also tried using this code

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(str(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=14)), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

But then I am getting following error:

```
time data '2017-06-04 14:26:18.941458+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

Can someone suggest how can I convert to the specific format. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a built in date parser that abstracts the logic of `strftime` away called [parse_datetime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.dateparse.parse_datetime). You can simply pass in a date string and it will return a `datetime.datetime` object. Here's what your code would look like:

```
from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
parse_datetime(str(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=14)))
>>> datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 7, 45, 28, 301957)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to convert the datetime.datetime() object into string, you could just do this,

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=14), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
'2017-06-04T14:45:23.621658+0000'
```

Or if you want it as the datetime object,

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(str(timezone.now() + timedelta(days=14))[:26], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 4, 14, 50, 26, 5649)
```